# Does Anyone Still Prefer N-Tier Architecture After Having *Shipped* an MVC Application?

Tags: model-view-controller, language-agnostic, stored-procedures, n-tier-architecture

- Other SO threads have asked people
  if they prefer N-Tier or MVC
  architecture.
- I'm not looking to
  continue that debate on this thread.
- I'm looking for something more specific.

My Question:

> Does Anyone Still Prefer N-Tier Architecture After Having *Shipped* an MVC Application?

Reason for My Question:

- Before I *shipped* an MVC web application, I wasn't convinced that it was superior to N-Tier Architecture.

  - Specifically, if better unit testing was the only obvious benefit of MVC, then I saw no reason to switch gears and adopt a new architecture.
- But after having shipped an MVC application, I can see many benefits (which have been enumerated on other threads).

Comment: It's community wiki, I think it's a valid question. If it's closed, I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: @Malfist: Thanks. I hope you can tell - I'm not looking for an argument. I want to learn. I want to know if I'm missing something.

Comment: So far I know, MVC and N-tier are different things which are not orthogonal. I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can say that I have used both and prefer N-Tier. I still think its cleaner in the end. I use Layergen http://www.icemanind.com/LayerGen.aspx which will automatically build the Data layers and Business Layers for me.